# Проверка сети в программе под Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, сеть

Нужен совет.

Пишу программу переводчик под WinPhone. Во время запроса к api переводчика отлавливаю ошибку таймаута подключения к интернету. Вот думаю, может включить при каждом нажатии кнопки "Перевод" проверку, дабы не заставлять пользователя ждать пока отловится ошибка, а сразу указать что сеть недоступна:

```
if (!DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
{
    // уведомляем что сеть недоступна
}
else
{
    // выполняем код перевода
}
```

Вот теперь думаю, а не будет ли это отнимать лишнее время и память на такую проверку?
Буду рад любым комментариям и советам.

Спасибо!

Comment: Эта проверка занимает по времени какие-то миллисекунды. В чем именно вопрос-то?

Comment: К тому же она проверяет не наличие доступа к интернету, а наличие подключения к телефонной сети, что не одно и то же.

Comment: @andreycha, разве? Откуда инфа?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/106/andreycha Эта проверка смотрит есть ли возможность подключиться к сети любым способом (сотовая сеть, wifi или ПК).
http://hashcode.ru/users/5357/olter Вопрос в том что имеет ли смысл ставить эту проверку или просто отлавливать сетевые ошибки try catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@dad495](/users/9158/dad495)](/users/9158/dad495), тут, в общем, дело обстоит так:

Задайте себе вопрос: насколько велик шанс, что у вашего приложения при нажатии кнопки "перевод" *внезапно* не окажется соединения с сетью?

Я бы сделал такую проверку один раз - при запуске приложения(а при нажатии на кнопку - обычный try-catch). Но в принципе, особой нагрузки эта проверка не добавляет (говорю по личному опыту, пусть меня поправят, если я не прав), т.е. вопрос в общем-то "Насколько параноидален программист, который это пишет?"

Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто стараюсь все учесть.